# jenkins pipeline deal with empty output from shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In a Jenkins pipeline, I am trying to retrieve the output of a shell script into a variable.

Example

```
list_test = sh(script:'ls | grep test', returnStdout:true).trim()
list_test.each { test -> 
   method(test)
}
```

This works fine as long as there is indeed an output.
The problem is when the output of 'ls | grep test' is empty.

I end up with an error.

So far, the only workaround I found was:

```
try {
   list_test = sh(script:'ls | grep test', returnStdout:true).trim()
}

catch (Exception ex) {
    println("output is empty")
}
if (list_test) {
   list_test.each { test -> 
      method(test)
   }
}
```

Would there be any better way to handle that kind of issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if grep is unable to find string, it will return non-zero exit code.

You can use something like that:

```
(ls|grep test)||echo "nothing found"
```

or you can use any command (replace 'sleep 1' with your favorite command), if you do not need any output:

```
(ls|grep test)||sleep 1
```